# Passing user from user session in Java to Firebird Trigger using Hibernate or JDBC

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, firebird, jaybird

I have a trigger that is used to audit data modifications. I need to send a query before every JDBC call so it sends user id to Firebird. How could I use it with Hibernate?

JDBC query example:

```
select rdb$set_context('USER_SESSION','CURRENT_USER', ?) from rdb$database
```

Comment: Are you using Hibernate directly, or as a JPA implementation (or, do you use `SessionFactory` or `EntityManagerFactory`)?

Comment: I'm using as JPA implementation, JTA data source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know of two ways to achieve this:

1. Execute a native query to set the value:

   ```
   EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
   Query contextSetQuery = em.createNativeQuery(
           "select rdb$set_context('USER_SESSION','CURRENT_USER', ?) from rdb$database");
   contextSetQuery.setParameter(1, "MARK_NATIVE");
   contextSetQuery.getSingleResult();

   // other stuff
   ```

   Getting the result is imperative, as fetching the result is what will actually set the context variable.
2. Unwrap to a Hibernate `Session` and set the client info property on the connection

   ```
   EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
   Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
   session.doWork(connection -> connection.setClientInfo("CURRENT_USER", "MARK_CLIENT_INFO"));

   // other stuff
   ```

   The Jaybird implementation of `Connection.setClientInfo` will do the same as the native query (and the query in your question).